# $\mathbb R$ with the topology generated by $\tau = \{(a, \infty): a \in \mathbb R\}$ is pseudocompact

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

I'm trying to solve the following question from the [UChicago GRE preparation](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Emin/GRE/) problem sets:

> Endow $\mathbb R$ with the right topology, generated by $\tau = \{(a, \infty): a \in \mathbb R\}$ and call this space $X$. Which of the following is false?
>
> (...)
>
> (E) $X$ is pseudocompact (every continuous function $f: X \to \mathbb R$ is bounded)

Per the answer key (E) is not false. I haven't heard of the term pseudocompactness before but I'm trying to work out things from the definition. If I understand correctly, the topology $\mathcal O_\tau$ generated by the basis $\tau$ is $\tau \cup (-\infty, +\infty) \cup \emptyset$. The basic property of continuous functions is that the pre-image of every open set is open. Using just this how do we show that $f: X \to \mathbb R$ is bounded?

Comment: For every $x$ the set $\{ y : f(x) - 1 < f(y) < f(x) + 1\}$ belongs to $\tau$.

Comment: Why are these tests so simple? I could do most of them after my 6 years of high school in Holland (in the 1980's). They're easier than the standard central maths exams. British A-levels are also harder than this. Is this to enter college?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $X$ has an even stronger property: every continuous real-valued function (in fact, every continuous function with values in a Hausdorff space) is constant. This follows from the fact that there every two nonempty open subsets of $X$ intersect.

Comment: I'm thinking about the hint. For any $x \in \mathbb R$, we have two disjoint open sets $A, B$ in $\mathbb R$ such that $A > x$ and $B < x$ and $A \cup x \cup B = \mathbb R$. To be more explicit, $A = (x, \infty)$ and $B = (-\infty, x)$. Then either the open set $f^{-1}(A)$ is empty or the open set $f^{-1}(B)$ is empty or both are empty. Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: @S.D.: try arguing the contrapositive: start with a non-constant function and show that it is necessarily discontinuous. Or if you prefer, argue by contradiction: suppose there is a non-constant continuous function. The former approach is better in my opinion, but the latter can be easier to think about.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f:X \to \Bbb R$ is continuous, and suppose $f$ were not constant. This means that there are $x_1 \neq x_2 \in X$ with $f(x_1) \neq f(x_2)$. Suppose (WLOG) that $f(x_1) < f(x_2)$ then find $c\in \Bbb R$ with $f(x_1) < c < f(x_2)$. Then $x_1 \in O_1 = f^{-1}[(-\infty,c)]$ is open and $x_2 \in O_2 = f^{-1}[(c, \infty)]$ is open too (both by continuity of $f$) and $O_1$ and $O_2$ are thus non-empty open and disjoint in $X$. This however does never happen as such sets in $X$ by definition are always of the form $(a, +\infty)$ and any two of these intersect (any point larger than the max of their boundary points is in the intersection).

So any continuous real-valued $f$ on $X$ is constant (so surely bounded), hence $X$ is pseudocompact.